# How to pick up values only when outside of text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently my javascript is written like the following, however, there is one problem with the script, that i am trying to fix... when the cursor is focused on input type text with id of "proxid", it still picks up the value typed.

I only want it to get values when the cursor isn't select in an input.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    switch(event.which){
        //stuff
    }
}
```

How do I check to see if the cursor is in focus on a input box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [:focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) selector to check if the cursor is currently on the input.

```
$('input').is(':focus');
```

So in your code, you could do:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if(!$('#myInput').is(':focus'))
    {
        //Run Code here when input is not focused.
    }   
});
```

**Demonstration:**  http://jsfiddle.net/afw3L/

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `tagName` of `document.activeElement`:

```
if (document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
    // an input element has focus
}
```

Or:

if (document.querySelector('input:focus').length > 0) {
        // an input element has focus
    }

References:

- [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement).
- [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).

Answer (score 0):

Better to maybe react to change of focus with:

*markup*

```
<input type="text" id="myEdit" />
```

*script*

```
   $('#myEdit').on('blur', function() {
      console.log(this.value);
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Saran/cqjHx/

Or, to encompass all inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/Saran/N86QG/